# How to turn off logging buffer to get logs in real time with python command line tool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, argparse

I have a command line tool which produces plenty of logs. I want these logs to be sent to `stdout` as soon as they're made. Right now, the program finishes everything (which can take several minutes), and then sends everything to `stdout` all at once. This means that currently, the user is not aware of whats going on internally, and I want to change that.

So far I've tried passing the `-u` flag as a command line argument, but that doesn't change anything. I have a feeling I need to use `logging.handlers.BufferingHandler` with `flush()` in some capacity, but I haven't been able to figure it out through tinkering.

```py
def some_func(flag: bool):
    if flag:
        logging.info('flag is truthy')
        return
    logging.warning('flag is falsy')
```

I'd like the above function to show the user one of those logs as soon as the log is created. 
Note: currently I set the logging level with `logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)`.

Thanks!

Comment: your warning log goes to `stdout`, not `stderr` [as described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library)?

Answer (score 3):

you have to set environmental variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

Answer (score -2):

Make use of `StreamHandler` in the logging module

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

This will dump all the logs on console

```
$ python simple_logging_module.py
2005-03-19 15:10:26,618 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,620 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,695 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,697 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2005-03-19 15:10:26,773 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
```

Comment: Im a little confused as to why you just copied and pasted code from [here](https://github.com/ksator/python-training-for-network-engineers/blob/master/logging-and-arguments/logging.md), but this solution doesn't produce logs to `stdout` in real time, so unfortunately it does not answer the question.

Comment: i have used the same handler in projects, it will stream all the logs to console afaik 
can you provide your logging config? 
and btw this is from official docs https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging

Comment: Right now the only place I configure logging is with `logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO if args.verbose else logging.WARNING)` inside an `if __name__ ==  '__main__':` block, after I parse the other command line args.

Comment: Please have a [look here] (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#useful-handlers). If you explicitly use a `MemoryHandler` or `BufferingHandler` the logs will go into the buffer and then you want to flush. are you saying that in OP?

Comment: Yes sir, thats what Im saying. I just need to get the logs out asap when the tool is running.